# Intent for png file inside the app

Tags: android, button, android-intent, android-image, android-gallery

I have a button in my app, and I want to preview an image from the gallery app when the button is clicked. How do I achieve this?

```
     howto = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
     howto.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

  //Intent..... show my png file using gallery (system app)

                }
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
   Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(
                  "content://media/internal/images/media"));
```

Comment: how to use   content://media/internal/images/media ??? i have a spesific png file inside my app

Answer (score 0):

**Try this.**

```
Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,THIS);
android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, RESULT_LOAD_IMG);
```